# Element goes abroad it's own background

Tags: html, css

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93D5P/).

But for some reason in **jsfiddle it works fine**, so I made screenshot of problem in my browser (Chrome):

[image]

```
    .hider{
        height: 15px;
        vertical-align: -1px;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: right;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
```

Link example:

```
 <a href="/tests/24/delete_key?position=10" class="hider" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" id="hide_10" rel="nofollow">x</a>
```

Comment: In my chrome it seems to work just fine as your Fiddle

Comment: Have you tried `line-height: normal;`?

Comment: @NathanLee, thank you very much, I will upvote if you add an answer

Comment: What other CSS is affecting this element? You can check in the Chrome DevTools by right-clicking the element and clicking Inspect Element.

Comment: FWIW: Height of an element content does not affect height of the element itself if height of the element is specified explicitly (as long as the element is not a part of a table). So you probably should not specify `height` for your element.

Comment: I have added my answer - @JoeHalfFace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to add a `line-height:normal;`. This will hopefully resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `vertical-align` & add `line-height`.

Also try to use shorthand CSS, to minimize your code.

```
#hide_10 {               
 height: 15px;
 width: 54px;
 background-color: #ffc400;
 margin-bottom: 0 0 4px 0;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: right;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: normal;
}
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93D5P/2/)